# Labels appearing buffered, but Python code is running unbuffered

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, buffered

I am currently creating a blackjack game using Python3 on Sublime Text. When the dealers cards are drawn one by one, you can see it being drawn one by one in the console using the `after()` to call on different functions, but in the actual GUI all the cards are appearing at the same time, right at the end.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
def d_pick_a_card():
    global d_hand
    global card
    global deck
    global d_counter
    global cvpath
    global cardvalue 
    global d_card_relx
    global cv 
    cardvalue = 0
    card = deck.pop(0)
    print('Drew',card)
    if card == 'J':
        cardvalue = 10
        cvpath = 11
    elif card == 'Q':
        cardvalue = 10
        cvpath = 12
    elif card == 'K':
        cardvalue = 10
        cvpath = 13
    elif card == 'A':
        cardvalue = 11
        cvpath = 14
    else:
        cardvalue = card
        cvpath = card
    d_hand.append(cardvalue)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    d_counter += 1

#THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT SHOWS THE VISUAL CARD ON THE GUI
def d_pick_vis(cardvalue, d_counter):
    global dealers_turn
    global card_frame
    card_frame = tk.Label(top, image = cv[cvpath]) 
    card_frame.place(relx= d_card_relx[d_counter], rely=.18, anchor='center')
    widgetList.append(card_frame)

def dturnfunc():
    global dealersturn_img
    holding_img1.pack_forget()
    dealersturn_img = tk.Label(top, image = dealersturn)
    dealersturn_img.img = dealersturnpath
    dealersturn_img.pack()
    top.after(500, dealers_turn())

def dealers_turn():
    global cardvalue
    global d_counter
    d_pick_a_card()
    d_pick_vis(cardvalue, d_counter)
    print("The Dealers hand is:", sum(d_hand))
    print('\n')
    if sum(d_hand) <= sum(hand):
        print('Dealer picks again')
        top.after(500,dealers_turn_2())
    elif sum(d_hand) == 21:
        print('Dealer Wins')
    elif sum(d_hand) >= 22:
        print('You win!')
    else:
        print('Dealer Wins')
```

Comment: Although this maybe wouldn't solve your problem.You should use `top.after(500, dealers_turn)` instead of `top.after(500, dealers_turn())`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the functions in your calls to `after()`, instead do this:

```
top.after(500, dealers_turn)  # Note: just pass in the name of the function

...

top.after(500, dealers_turn_2)
```

You need to pass in a reference to the function and `after()` will `call` that function after the time elapses.

When you were calling the functions yourself, you pass in the return value, which is probably `None` which, I'm guessing, `after()` ignores.